# Redirect from folder containing website

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite, drupal

I have a website reached from this url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/cms/index.php
```

being served from this directory:

```
public_html/cms/index.php
```

In public_html I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteRule (.*) cms/$1 [L]
```

Which lets me get to the site like this:

http://www.mysite.com/index.php

But now if I reference the 'old' address, I'd like to redirect to the rewritten address with a permanent redirect code.

for example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/cms/?q=node/1
is redirected to...
http://www.mysite.com/?q=node/1
```

How can I make this happen?

EDIT:
Also in the .htaccess file supplied with Drupal(cms), this is written.  I've tried enabling it, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
```

EDIT:  Including more of my .htaccess file - seems relevant.

```
  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. 
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]


  #Strip cms folder from url
  RewriteRule (.*) cms/$1 


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
  RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

  <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
  # Serve correct encoding type.
  Header append Content-Encoding gzip
  # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
  Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect 301, not mod_rewrite.

Examples via googlefu:  http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

Edit: or R=301 in your rewrite flags.

Comment: Would a redirect work?  I still want the user to get to the correct page - just strip out the folder.

Comment: In your case, the redirect rewrite will need to go in a .htaccess file that's located in your /cms folder (as opposed to the one you have here in your root public directory), since htaccess works on a per-directory basis.

Comment: It would be simple, too -- so your /cms/.httaccess would probably look something like..  RewriteEngine On, RewriteBase /, RewriteRule (.*) %1 [R=301]  ... I think that should work.  Ooh, but now I'm wondering if that may mess with Drupal's internal links.  It's worth a shot.